# Memory allocation for c++ objects with new gets the same address when app runs on Android device

Tags: android, c++, memory, allocation

1. Android app uses C++ shared lib to do search, searches are done via tasks, tasks are c++ objects, allocated as below:

   SearchTaskPtr task(new MySearchTask(shared_from_this(), str2Search));

   outputlog("Search task %p allocated for str2Search=%s", task.get(), str2Search.c_str());

   queueTask(task);
2. The app runs into a state that, the allocated tasks are at the same address, can see from the log:

   Search task 0x667c80a0 allocated for str2Search=ma

   Search task 0x667c80a0 allocated for str2Search=mat

   Search task 0x667c80a0 allocated for str2Search=math

   Search task 0x667c80a0 allocated for str2Search=mathe
3. When the issue happens, the tasks are still in the queue.

Can anyone shed light here on how a same address new'ed for different objects?

```
Device-info:
OS Version: 3.0.31-310959(N7100XXALJ3)
Android: 4.1.1
OS API Level: 16
Device: t03g
Model (and Product): GT-N7100 (t03gxx)
Manufacture: samsung
Display: JRO03C.N7100XXALJ3
Brand: samsung
```

Comment: Any code we can look at? Otherwise I'd personally be guessing at why it's giving the same address.

Comment: The code is between #1 and #2 above. Thanks.

Comment: Are the tasks being deallocated between those log lines? Without seeing the definitions of SearchTaskPtr and queueTask, I can only guess. But if SearchTaskPtr is something like a unique_ptr and you're leaving it pointing to the object when it goes out of scope, then it's going to delete the object.

Comment: The tasks not deallocated, the tasks get executed,

Comment: Depending on a number of factors, it's possible for code to use an object after it has been deallocated and appear to work successfully. You might try putting a logging statement in the task object's destructor just to make sure. If that's not the issue, then the only other thing I can think of it that you're somehow corrupting the heap in just such a way that it ends up believing it can re-use that memory.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are passing a shared_pointer to this object in the constructor so as soon as the task  object goes out of scope ,the heap memory is released for re-use as I think that object doesn't have any other shared pointer sharing the reference.Complete code would help better.